# Python QuickSort returning original input

Tags: python, sorting

So here is my quicksort code

```
def quicksort(A):
    if len(A) > 1:
        pivot = A[0]
        L = []
        E = []
        R = []
        for i in A:
            if i < pivot:
                L.append(i)
            elif i == pivot:
                E.append(i)
            else:
                R.append(i)
        quicksort(L)
        quicksort(R)
        A = L + E + R
```

And the output when I run

```
array = [5,6,3,2,7]
print "original array" + str(array)
quicksort(array)
print "sorted array" + str(array)
```

Is

```
original array[5, 6, 3, 2, 7]
sorted array[5, 6, 3, 2, 7]
```

However, when I step through the function with the debugger, the last value A ever holds is [2,3,5,6,7] which is sorted, why does A not hold this after the function is executed?

Comment: the *A* is not a pointer from *array* ; in function you change *A* , and *array* no changed !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You build a *new* list `A = L + E + R`, rebinding the local name. The original list is unaffected.

You need to *return* the new list objects:

```
def quicksort(A):
    if len(A) > 1:
        pivot = A[0]
        L = []
        E = []
        R = []
        for i in A:
            if i < pivot:
                L.append(i)
            elif i == pivot:
                E.append(i)
            else:
                R.append(i)
        L = quicksort(L)
        R = quicksort(R)
        return L + E + R
    return A
```

This returns a new list object:

```
>>> quicksort([5,6,3,2,7])
[2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

Alternatively, update the list in-place by using slice assignment:

```
def quicksort(A):
    if len(A) > 1:
        pivot = A[0]
        L = []
        E = []
        R = []
        for i in A:
            if i < pivot:
                L.append(i)
            elif i == pivot:
                E.append(i)
            else:
                R.append(i)
        quicksort(L)
        quicksort(R)
        A[:] = L + E + R
```

Now the original list is altered in-place:

```
>>> lst = [5,6,3,2,7]
>>> quicksort(lst)
>>> lst
[2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: He doesn't _need_ to return them; he's trying to mutate the values in-place, and that's a perfectly reasonable and doable thing, he just didn't do it right.

Comment: @abarnert: Hrm, I guess with creating new `L` and `R` objects that's feasible.

Comment: It's not just feasible, he's almost got it right. See my answer—just change `A = ` to `A[:] = `, and his code works exactly as desired.

Comment: @abarnert: yeah, I was assuming that the recursive calls required to have lower and upper bounds passed along, before I saw that these calls are given a new list object.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was originally doing it with return values but for a reason specific to my homework assignment it works better when I just mutate the list in place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the last line doesn't do what you seem to think it does:

```
A = L + E + R
```

This adds L, E, and R together into a new list, and binds that new list to the local variable `A`. It doesn't affect the list that `A` used to be bound to in any way.

What you probably wanted to do was replace the contents of the existing list that `A` is bound to. Like this:

```
A[:] = L + E + R
```

---

You ask "why does A not hold this after the function is executed?" Well, after the function is executed, `A` doesn't exist at all. That's the whole point of a local variable.

Of course `array` exists. And `array` and `A` are originally references to the same list. If you mutate that list, you get what you want. If you make `A` refer to a different list, you don't.